# A receiving and sending TCP client with Go

Tags: go, p2p, tcp

I am trying to implement my own P2P network without using any library. I want to build a TCP Client which sends and receives messages from other nodes. So all nodes should be able to send and receive messages over tcp/ip.

My current Problem is that the when I start both clients: One Node is able to receive and send messages, but the other node just sends messages and cannot receive messages.

I think I need to implement a channel somehow, but I am really new into Go and don't know how to implement it. Any suggestions?

Code below:

Main.go:

```
package main

 func main() {

  address := "127.0.0.1:8081" // IP of the other node; hardcoded for now
  go startServer()
  startClient(address)

}
```

helpler.go :

```
package main

import (
 "bufio"
 "fmt"
 "net"
 "os"
) 

func startClient(address string) {
 //connect to this socket
 connClient, _ := net.Dial("tcp", address)

for {

    //read in input from stdin
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Text to send: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    //send to socket
    fmt.Fprint(connClient, text+"\n")

    //listen for reply
    //message, _ := bufio.NewReader(connClient).ReadString('\n')
    //fmt.Print("Message from server: " + message)
  }
 }
func startServer() {
 fmt.Println("Starting...")

//listen on all interfaces
ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")

//accept connection on port
connServer, _ := ln.Accept()

//run loop forever
for {
    //will listen for message to process ending in newline(\n)
    message, _ := bufio.NewReader(connServer).ReadString('\n')

    //fmt.Print("Message Received:" + string(message))

    //sample process for string received
    //newmessage := strings.ToUpper(message)

    connServer.Write([]byte(message + "\n"))
  }
 }
```

Comment: One issue is that the loop in StartServer creates and discards a bufio.Reader along with any data buffered by that reader.  Create the bufio.Readers once per connection.

Comment: Thanks, but it is in the loop to create a bidrectional channel, so that sending endless messages between the nodes is provided. Not just sending a "ping"

Comment: The program discards buffered data. That is probably not what you want. Also, the value returned by ReadString includes the traiing \n.  Another \n is added on write.  If you are not intending to send a blank line with every message, then don't add the extra \n.

Comment: Don't ignore errors. You cannot have both servers listen on the same host:port.

Comment: You mean for sending messages a port and receiving messages a port?

Comment: No, you can't listen on the same port twice. If you were checking errors, you'd see an error stating that the port is already in use when you try to `net.Listen` on 8081 when something is already listening on that port.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve but [this talk](https://talks.golang.org/2012/chat.slide#18) by Andrew Gerrand helped me to start with simple networking in Go. It probably gives you an idea how to implement your server, too.

Answer (score 3):

Newbie Go developer here, but there is one issue I can think off right off the bat. You can not have multiple processes listening in the same IP and port.

You are likely having an issue with that,  but because you are not checking for errors you are not catching it. If you had code to check for errors you likely would notice you are getting an error like this:

> 2018/07/11 09:21:06 listen tcp 127.0.0.1:8081: bind: address already
>
> in use exit status 1

Even if somehow that is not your issue, it is still a good idea to have the error checks.

I recommend you add checks. For example

**Server side**

```
ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

**Client side**

```
  conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }
```

> I think I need to implement a channel somehow

As stated, I am new to Go myself, but my understanding is that channels are an interprocess communication tool within the same program. Not related to multiple programs. If you search for go channels in your favorite search tool you can find more info, but don't believe it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two different processes as server and client.

For example, at the main function:

```
func main() {
    connType := os.Getenv("TYPE")

    if connType == "server" {
        startServer()
    } else if connType == "client" {
        startClient()
    } else {
        log.Println("please provide the TYPE arg (TYPE=server or TYPE=client)")
    }
}
```

Then you can run `TYPE=server go run yourapp` and `TYPE=client go run yourapp`.
You can look at this GitHub repo https://github.com/johannesridho/protobuf-over-tcp.